# Google Analytics API V3 / OAuth 2

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've desperately tried to figure this out on my own, and did not want to come to SO with this question, but I'm at my wits end (no thanks to the api / oauth docs).

I'm working in PHP and I'm trying to avoid using the `Google_Client` and `AnalyticsService` classes, by using REST on the `analytics.data.ga.get` method.

`STEP #1: Create an API Project for a Web Application`

I go to the [api console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and create a project with analytics services and get an OAuth Client ID and Secret.

I'm under the impression that I can create a Client ID for an [Installed Application](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#installed) or a [Web Application](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#webserver) because I'm doing the initial token handshaking manually.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I create a Client ID for web applications and get my Client ID `xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com`, Client secret `yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy`, and my Redirect URI is `http://localhost:9002`

`STEP #2: Request initial API access`

I enter this link; `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9002&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&access_type=offline`

The `access_type=offline` is because I'm using REST, and do not expect "the user" (myself) to manually deal with redirects / popups every time I need a refreshed token.

The above request returns `http://localhost:9002?code=4/KModH0K_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9Iw.gikOaYRDWywTshQV0ieZDArCOX8XdwI`

Code `4/KModH0K_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9Iw.gikOaYRDWywTshQV0ieZDArCOX8XdwI` is my permission to request the API Token.

`STEP #3: Request First Token`

Because of my company’s IT issues, I’m forced to use PHP 5.2.17 and I do not have access to PHP cURL, so I’m using `file_get_contents` and `stream_context_create`.

The first token is requested with a PHP `file_get_contents()`;

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => 'code=4/KModH0K_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9Iw.gikOaYRDWywTshQV0ieZDArCOX8XdwI&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9002&grant_type=authorization_code'
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', false, $context);
var_dump($result);
```

The content parameters must be in a single line.

The above code returns my `access_token` and `refresh_token` in json format

`string(195) "{ "access_token" : "ya29.AHES6wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwVEBXE6XRbC-Q-pP0wZWdoIm9H804ro", "token_type" : "Bearer", "expires_in" : 3600, "refresh_token" : "1/8tXvdUKcSEcaaxVqqqqqqqqqqqqqoYpj2KSS9qwWI" }"`

The refresh token I must store in a safe place, like a DB or protected txt file, which is called upon when my access_token has timed out.

`STEP #4: Request Analytics Data`

Now from what I understand, I’m ready to roll and should be able to use my `access_token` to make requests to `https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga`.

I do this by sending this request;

```
$request = 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga' .
    '?ids=ga%3Aaaaaaaaa' .
    '&start-date=2012-12-07' .
    '&end-date=2012-12-09' .
    '&metrics=ga%3Avisits';

$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n' .
                    'Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHES6wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwVEBXE6XRbC-Q-pP0wZWdoIm9H804ro \r\n'
        )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents($request, FALSE, $context);
var_dump($result);
```

This request returns a `401 Unauthorized` error.  I take this as meaning my request is properly formed and making the connection to `https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga`.

Also, according to this doc [Getting Full Quota](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#quota), I can make the request with the `access_token` in the URL like this;

```
$request = 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga' .
    '?ids=ga%3A48564799' .
    '&access_token=ya29.AHES6wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwVEBXE6XRbC-Q-pP0wZWdoIm9H804ro' .
    '&start-date=2012-12-07' .
    '&end-date=2012-12-09' .
    '&metrics=ga%3Avisits';

$result = file_get_contents($request, FALSE);

$result = json_decode($result);

var_dump($result);
```

This time I receive `403 error`, in which google includes the response `User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile`.

`QUESTION #1`

Am I’m missing something in the API console or a process in the token acquisition?  I’m assuming I’m not, because I’m ultimately acquiring the `access_token=ya29` and refresh token.

`QUESTION #2`
Maybe I’m completely off basis in assuming I can do this with simple https reqests?  Do I have to use the `Google_Client` and `AnalyticsService` classes?  I don’t think this is the case, but maybe I’m wrong.

`QUESTION #3`
Do I need to use a ‘key’ in my request?
`&key=bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb`

`QUESTION #4`

By using PHP 5.2.17 am I missing something? (besides 5.3 or 5.4 themselves)

For example, in some versions of PHP, in `stream_context_create`, the header should be in an array and not a string, like this;

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHES6wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwVEBXE6XRbC-Q-pP0wZWdoIm9H804ro '
        )
    )
);
```

But I don’t think that it’s an issue in my case.  I’m just curious if these HTTP request need to be formed a different way (without using curl).

Any insights and thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you look into the 403 - insufficient permissions error and make sure that the un/pw combo you are using has access to the profile?

Comment: Access Tokens last for 1 hour before they need to be refreshed.  Are you getting a new Access Token with the Refresh token?

Comment: @jk  I’m not sure what you mean by username and password combo.  Doesn’t the `access_token` represent the credentials?  I didn’t see anywhere in the docs (besides maybe when using the classes) that un/pw are necessary.  I definitely haven’t seen any parameters for simple get requests.

Comment: @M Schenkel  Yes, I’m checking the state of ‘access_token’ with the endpoint `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ya29.AHES6wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwVEBXE6XRbC-Q-pP0wZWdoIm9H804ro`  and refreshing when necessary.

Comment: BTW, here are the docs describing all of the parameters for `https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga`  [Getting Full Quota](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#quota) As you can see - in the Query Parameters Summary - there are no parameters for username and password.

Comment: What I mean is: Is the user with the un/pw combo you are using added with the proper permissions to the GA profile that you are trying to pull data from? [Add/modify/delete users](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1009702)

Comment: @jk. I see. You mean adding the api email address `xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com` as a user to the analytics profile?  Yeah, that hasn't worked either.

Comment: @jk. You inadvertently helped me solve my problem by getting me to think about passwords. I made an idiotic mistake. Thanks for your help. See below.

Comment: Sometimes that happens. We all do it from time to time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here’s my dim witted mistake that nearly gave me a heart attack.

I typically do my development work in Chrome.  And my Chrome browser was signed into my gmail account `personal@gmail.com`.  However, my analytics account, which is under my `work@gmail.com` was open in FireFox (try not to laugh to hard).

I’m not 100% sure this is correct, but I think this is the general flow.  When I did `STEP #2: Request initial API access`, I did this in my Chrome browser.  The endpoint `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` was authorizing my personal@gmail.com account.  And my STEP #4 API request `https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga` was looking for an analytics profile under my personal@gmail.com account.  Which of course doesn’t exist.

I literally wasted 15 hours on this.  This is dumber than trying to troubleshoot an update… and forgetting to flush the cache.

Sorry for wasting your time.

**EDIT** REFRESH TOKENS

I've once again run into issues with this API and found out the hard way that GA will revoke Refresh Tokens if too many different clients use the token, at least I think that was the problem.

Further reading can be [found here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline).

Comment: Thanks.  I've had to return to this post again to figure out my mistakes with this API. It's never easy.

Comment: These sorts of problems are quiet common with authentication I think. Maybe there should be a better way to debug them.

Answer (score 10):

I got a 403 today and found the cause: in the `get` function I was using the account ID instead of the profile ID. Switching to the profile ID fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes that's correct, it’s always the “Profile ID” and not the account or property ID (which looks like “UA-xxx”). The Profile ID is for a specific web property and can be found in the Admin->Profiles->Profile Settings tab, it’s an integer with no dashes.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with CURL request. In the `GoogleAnalyticsAPI.class.php > class Http > function curl (around line 720)` add one more option to stop CURL from verifying the peer's certificate:

**`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`**