# Google Contacts API - You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to get my Google Contacts API key. I created a new project and enabled Google Contacts API. After that when I go to "Credentials" tab, I got this error: ERROR You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page. (please see the screen shot).[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Google Analytics API: "User does not have sufficient permissions for this account."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959942/google-analytics-api-user-does-not-have-sufficient-permissions-for-this-accoun)

> give the service account email

Comment: but this api is for android , I am not using contacts api for android instead in java web app