# How to create view in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

How do you create a view within Google Analytics v4?  I am trying to query for Analytics data, specifically conversion information.  However, I cannot find adequate documentation for this new version.  I have been following this guide. There is not a "create view" button has referenced in the older documentation.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py

I am using a "Web + App" app which I assume is v4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In **Google Analytics 4** (*App+Web*) **you will no longer see the “View” column** (as you had with Universal Analytics) as there are no Views in this new type of property (settings and capabilities usually done in View can now be done within the new property, and other reasons, such as creating country specific Views, can be accomplished with a quick Filter in the new property).

Comment: Thanks. That helps but also leaves me wondering if another API exists for this new version.   How would I programmatically query for data?

Comment: You can connect and use BigQuery where you can find row data.

Comment: @MichelePisani Previously export of data to BigQuery was restricted only to GA360 customers, right? With the new addition of GA4, can we now export data into BigQuery using just GA(free) as well? Could you please share your thoughts

Comment: Yes, you can. You have to connect BigQuery with GA4 Property.

Comment: In GA 4, filters are also disabled, where did you find that.